# Trying to think of a novel I read in the mid 80s set in a dystopian future

Tags: story-identification

A novel set in a future where the society lived in a closed maybe underground community where they were all telepathic. Punishment was to be cut off from other people’s thoughts. 
The main character was a teenage girl who rebelled against her controlled society and was punished as above but eventually escaped or was expelled. Outside was a wasteland but people did live there and there was hope and they were free. 
I remember reading a number of different books by the same author, who was a woman I think. Most of them were science fiction but one was historical set in a Native American tribe.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206675/dystopian-novel-where-telepathic-humans-live-under-a-dome (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be The Dream Catcher by Monica Hughes? It's a sequel to Devil on My Back.
"Ruth is a misfit. Within the protective Dome of Ark Three, she alone disrupts the Web, the perfect pattern formed by the psychic joining of minds. Other images fill Ruth's dreams, images of a red-haired girl from the far eastern mountains. Could it be that other Arks exist? Ruth must face a hazardous journey as she becomes involved in a dangerous rescue operation..".

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps thinking of Pamela Sargent's *[Watchstar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/869253.Watchstar)*?

> Alone in the desert, Daiya is faced with dilemma that will determine her fate. If she can successfully resolve it she will join the Net of her village, but if she fails, her life will be spent with the feared Merged Ones. Confused and torn between worlds near and far, Daiya harbors a secret of her people, and must find a way to move beyond her discoveries to a safe place where she can survive.

*[Climb the Wind](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1056082.Climb_The_Wind)* may be the Native American book you're thinking of.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: And if so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100587/looking-for-a-book-i-read-in-the-80s-probably-older-with-technology-powered-t?noredirect=1&lq=1