# Story (series) identification: Mind controlling satellite, a return to Earth, and two warring alien species

Tags: story-identification, novel, mind-control

I'm trying to find a series of stories (a trilogy, I think) with a slew of distinctive features. I can't remember when the books were written (I read them about a year and a half ago), but I can remember several points about the story:

1. It begins in a peaceful city controlled by a matriarchy.
2. Young men and women are tutored in the ways of the world by 'Aunts' and 'Uncles' (who have no actual familial connection).
3. The whole world is actually a colony whose inhabitants are being prevented from developing scientifically by a highly complex mind controlling satellite.
4. The satellite starts to break down, allowing some (including one particularly successful warlord) to fight it's control and develop destructive technologies.
5. The satellite loads itself up with some people (the protagonists) and heads back to Earth for repair.
6. Earth has changed and is now home to two sentient species, one avian ('angels', I seem to recall) and the other subterranean (and fond of sculpture).
7. These two species are in conflict, but are also intricately linked with each other's breeding behaviour.
8. The humans, returned from the colony by the mind controlling satellite, create peace between the two civilisations.

There are so many disparate elements here that I'm beginning to wonder if I just made the whole thing up in a fever dream. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Telepathic satellites sounds familiar - there was a series of books by Pamela Sargent that I asked a story-id on myself and eventually found.  I admit, I don't remember avians vs molemen being part of it.  If you don't remember when it was written, at least add when you read it, that can eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: @Radhil: Added the info. It's so short a time ago that I'm honestly embarrassed I've forgotten!

Comment: This was [my question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82766/38235), and here's [another one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100587/38235), either of these books/plots sound familiar?  Or not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Radhil Neither sound familiar, though both sound intriguing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like the Homecoming Saga (A trilogy) by Orson Scott Card.  It starts out in a very ancient city (40 million years) on a world where the people are kept from developing along certain warlike technological lines by a mind control satellite, whose breakdown forms a major plot point.  For instance, magnetic levitation is an available technology, but plain wheeled wagons are not because they can be used to haul soldiers.  Young men are tutored in sex by their Aunties, although I don't remember anything about Uncles.  IIRC, it was scifi retelling of the book of Mormon.  I don't recall any aliens, but I only read the first book.
**Edit**:-
The 'aliens'are in fact genetically modified terrestrial bats (who call themselves angels).
They are locked in an eternal war with GM rats (devils)

Comment: Indeed it is, though there are 5 books in all, not three. Blame my faulty memory for that one! Thank you!